# Why my github connection stopped working without any change

Tags: git, github, ssh

I had been using Github on my personal Mac and IntelliJ for long time.
In fact, I run spring-boot config server also on local backed by Git repo on github, and all had been working fine .until today.
Today suddenly, my local config server stopped working.
I tried and not able to use IntelliJ to push code to Github

So I tried using the terminal, but I've got the following error today.

```
MacBook-Pro ~ %  ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
The authenticity of host '[ssh.github.com]:443 ([192.30.253.123]:443)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

Until yesterday all was working fine. I was not even using the Terminal, I had been committing and pushing code through Intellij. But today everything is failing.

I pressed yes in the above command. And got the following message

```
Warning: Permanently added '[ssh.github.com]:443,[192.30.253.123]:443' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi xxxxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But I'm still not able to push or infect connect the GitHub.
I checked the files in `~/.ssh` folder. Nothing was changed since December.
I checked my Github Profile settings ssh key, nothing changed since December.

But suddenly today everything stopped working.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you push code manually from the terminal with something like `git push origin`?  If not, what's the error?  And what does `git remote -v` say?

Comment: I'm really not sure what happened. Everything is working now.
And yes, I tried from terminal `git push git remote` etc, everything was failing.

The only difference is, I was using public wifi in a coffee shop. at home, I used the exact same command, in fact, pressed up arrow and pressed enter in terminal and it worked

Answer (score 0):

> The only difference is, I was using public wifi in a coffee shop.

Double-check if this is working again (at the coffee shop); at least from command-line:

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:me/myrepo
# or
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -p 443'
git ls-remote git@ssh.github.com:me/myrepo
```